# Listing Values If they are not in the another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables. First is `SKU`, the second is `Isbn`. SKU has `SKU` column and Isbn has `asin` column.

SKU Table Example:

```
   Id       SKU
  1        k1 1111
  2        k9 1111
  3        k1 3333
  4        k2 5555
  5        k5 1111
  6        k5 6666
  7        k1 7777
  8        k7 8888
  9        k1 2222
 10        k2 4444
```

Isbn Table Example:

```
Id      asin
1       1111
2       2222
3       3333
4       4444
5       5555
```

I want to select the values If SKU column do not contain asin values. For the above table case, I want to get the following output since 6666, 7777, 8888 are not in asin column

Expected Output:

```
6        k5 6666
7        k1 7777
8        k7 8888
```

I selected the SKU values if they are in any of the asin column by doing following code.

```
SELECT [SKU].SKU
FROM Isbn, SKU
WHERE [SKU].SKU Like "*" & Isbn.asin & "*";
```

However, I need the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need wildcards (as in your example), simply do:

```
SELECT [SKU].SKU
FROM SKU
WHERE [SKU].SKU NOT IN (SELECT asin FROM Isbn.asin);
```

Comment: Although my Isbn table is in the ms-access, I got this error:  Could not find the file 'C\..\Isbn.mdb'.

Comment: I figured this error by deleting .asin part at the end of code. But I got full SKU values this time

Comment: By the way, sku values contain asin values, they do not exactly match